# convert a string to its type in .net

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string `` "System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.String]" ``, I want to convert this to the underlying .net type `` Type.GetType("System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.String]") `` returns null. Can any one out help me on this.

Comment: Show your code.. Your question isn't clear..

Comment: A string is a just string, you can't just convert it to another type, just like you can't convert the string "Apple" to an actual apple.

Comment: I think you will have to do some parsing of the string since this is a generic type.

Comment: google for "Type.GetType generics" (like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743367/why-i-cannot-use-type-gettype-in-generics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly include the assembly, version, and public key token (if it has one).

If you're running `.NET 4`, try this

```
Type t = Type.GetType("System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.String], System.Core, "
     + "Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089");
```

The reason you don't always have to fully qualify the string is because the extra information can be omitted if the type is within the current assembly or in the Mscorlib assembly. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/w3f99sx1.aspx):

> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See
>   AssemblyQualifiedName. If the type is in the currently executing
>   assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name
>   qualified by its namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a real non-abstract type signature? For example `` Type.GetType("System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[System.String]") `` should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using `Type.Name` instead of `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName`.