# Why does Select(x => ...Cast<x.GetType()>()) not work?

Tags: c#, linq, select, casting, typeof

Why does the following code produce an error?

```
var listOfList = new List<List<string>>();
var tmp = listOfList.Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y).Cast<x.GetType()>());
```

Error:

> Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'System.Type'

The code looks silly, because it's extremly simplified from my real example. I just wonder why it does not work exactly. It works if I replace `x.getType()` with `List<string>`, but I don't now the type of x at runtime.
For clarification: I don't necessary look for a solution. I want to know what exactly is wrong with my code.

Comment: `Cast<T>` requires the type to be known at compile time.

Comment: Why are you casting `x` to `x`? What's the point of that?

Comment: What is the use of casting to some type you don't know?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743367/why-i-cannot-use-type-gettype-in-generics

Comment: Also, `x` is a `List<string>`, but by calling `OrderBy` on it you perform a conversion creating a new `System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable<string>` object (which isn't a `List<string>`) so it cannot be cast to a `List<string>`.

Comment: thanks @Ric that's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: thanks @AmitKumarGhosh this looks interesing, I will have a look.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh It seems like MakeGenericType does not help either. I tried `Cast<typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(x))>()` but get the error `The type of namespace name 'x' could not be found`.

Comment: again you have to pass `string`. `x` has no compile time type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to write the code is to use `ToList` instead of `Cast` as mentioned elsewhere.

However to answer the question "what exactly is wrong with my code?" there are two specific points to start with:

- Using `Cast<x.GetType()>()`:

Generics are used with compile time type variables, so putting `Cast<List<string>>()` would make more sense here - the `x.GetType()` will only be resolved at run time. I guess the actually message you're getting is a result of the compiler getting muddled over this point.

- Attempting to cast to `List<string>`:

Even if specific cast code syntax was reasonable, the actual cast would still fail. At this point you're attempting to cast an `OrderedEnumerable<string>` to a `List<string>`. This isn't a valid cast. The `ToList()` resolves the otherwise un-resolved orderby statement to a list.

Answer (score 2):

Why you need to do this? I guess you need this code

```
var listOfList = new List<List<string>>();
var tmp = listOfList.Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y).ToList());
```

Comment: I've up-voted, but you really haven't answered the question - "Why does Select(x => …Cast<x.GetType()>()) not work?"

Comment: As mentioned, my real code example looks way different. The correct answer was given in the comments already though: `Cast<T>` requires the type to be known at compile time.

Comment: This code in my VS was compiled failure,there is no way to work!